# docker-compose - HTTP_USER & HTTP_PASSWORD not working

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I added to my docker-compose in environment:

```
HTTP_USER: admin
HTTP_PASSWORD: pass
```

When I opened localhost, I see authentication, but bellow login and password not working.

What is wrong, what I should add?

I using nginx-reverse proxy as http server.

My complete docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  ubuntuvnc-withpass:
    container_name: sub.domain.com
    image: dorowu/ubuntu-desktop-lxde-vnc
    expose:
      - "5900"
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: sub.domain.com
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST:  sub.domain.com
      VNC_PASSWORD:  pass
      RESOLUTION: 800x600
      HTTP_USER: admin
      HTTP_PASSWORD: pass
    networks:
     - proxy
 
networks:
  proxy:
    external:
      name: nginx_default
```

Comment: I think additional information is needed here

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.